# Fetch Api unable to add and update php cart session

Tags: javascript, php, next.js, fetch-api

I am new to Next.js and have been trying to connect to a cart session in a PHP file hosting at localhost/aits from the Next.js app which runs at `localhost:3000` in the same folder localhost/aits.

For some reason, the fetch API I am using in the Next.js app to add data to the cart is actually not setting the session with data. When I `console.log` the data session returned from the fetch API, I see the session set for the current product added but when I open a new browser to go to the cart URL, there are no products in it. Also when I add another product to the cart, it overrides the previous cart instead of adding to it or updating it.

It seems sessions do not work for fetch apis between `localhost:3000` and a PHP file that resides in the same localhost folder as the Next.js app.

```js
/* Next js file */

const ticketData = {
    pageId: id,
        discount: discount ? discount : 0
    };

    let fd = new FormData();
    for(const name in ticketData) {
        fd.append(name, ticketData[name]);
    }

    let resp = await fetch(`http://localhost/aits/add-to-cart.php`,{
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'same-origin', //I also used 'include' but same results
        body: fd
    })

    let data = await resp.json()

    console.log(data);
```

```php
/* Add to cart PHP  file */

$data = $_SESSION['kcart'];

function Exists($index, $array)
{
    if (array_key_exists($index, $array))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

if(Exists($pgName, $data['items'])) {
    $data['items']["c<cms:show k_page_name />"]['quantity'] += $productCount;
    $data['items']["c<cms:show k_page_name />"]['line_total'] += ($productCount * <cms:show pp_price />);
    $subTotal = $data['sub_total'] + ($productCount * <cms:show pp_price />);
    $discount = $data['discount'] + ($productCount * <cms:if discount gt '0'><cms:show discount /><cms:else/>0</cms:if>);

    //print_r($data['items']["c<cms:show k_page_name />"]);
    $action_status['status'] = 'ok';
    $action_status['status_msg'] = 'Pdt updated';

} else {
    $newItem = array
    (
        "line_id" => md5("c"."<cms:show k_page_name />"), 
        "id" => "<cms:show k_page_id />",
        "name" => "<cms:show k_page_name />",
        "title" => "<cms:show k_page_title />",
        "link" => "<cms:show k_page_link />",
        "price" => "<cms:show pp_price />",
        "quantity" => "<cms:show qty />",
        "line_total" => "<cms:mul qty pp_price />",
        "skip_line_total" => "0",
        "options" => "Array()",
        "requires_shipping" => "1",
        "product_thumb" => "<cms:show pp_product_thumb />",
        "previous_price" => "<cms:show pp_previous_price />",
        "discount_scale" => "",
        "shipping_scale" => "",
        "orig_price" => "<cms:show pp_price />",
        "line_discount" => "0"
    );
    $data['items']['c'."<cms:show k_page_name />"] = $newItem;
}
```

Comment: presumably ALL pages have `session_start();` at the beginning?

Comment: `credentials: 'same-origin'` is pointless - your request _is_ cross-origin, as the port is part of the origin. You need to use `include`, and you need to make sure that your API endpoint responds correctly (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` needs to be explicitly specified, a wildcard is not allowed in this scenario.)

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, yes all my pages have session_start(); at the beginning

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much. You just saved me 4 days of headache.